# Algorithm to get as close to zero as possible by subtracting only allowed numbers from a starting point

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, optimization, time-complexity

Let's say we have an arbitrary integer, ***position*** that equals `1850`

We also have an array of integers, ***components*** that equals `[150, 200, 500]`

We can reach the zero by:

1. Subtract `components[2]` from `position` three times (500*3), making it 350
2. Subtract `components[1]` from `position`, making it 150
3. Subtract `components[0]` from `position`, making it 0

So, using integers from the components array, I subtracted from `position` until there was as little left as possible (0)

---

Coded example:

```
var components = [500, 750, 1000];
var position = 2250;

position -= components[1]; // goal is now 1500
position -= components[0] * 3; // goal is now 0
```

[visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcKhj.png)

---

**The question:** is there an algorithm to determine the best way to reach zero from a number by subtracting only allowed numbers?

It would be highly preferrable that the algorithm uses the least number of components / subtractions possible.

I've tried a few naive methods like brute forcing, but that isn't ideal as performance is quite important in my application.

Comment: Either https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: What about DFS or A*-Search ?

Comment: Depending of the values of the `components `you can heavily reduce the search-space. 500*2 = 1000 -> we can always reduce 2 usages of 500 by one of 1000. Also 2*750=1500=3*500 -> we can always replace  two usages of 750 by 3*500. Or 4*750 by 3*1000. We also know that we need to use 750 at least once to get 2250 because no other component can produce the 50. ...

Comment: You can approach this problem as a dynamic programming task. The goal is to find the minimum number of components (integers from the components array) to subtract from the position such that it becomes zero or as close to zero as possible.

Comment: You could use backtracking. Start by subtracting the biggest component as often as possible and when you cannot reach 0 backtrack and try other components.

Comment: This could also be cast as a very simple IP (Integer Program).  You have described 3 competing objectives that you would need to weight somehow:  (1) get close to zero, (2) use as few "components" as possible, (3) use as few operations as possible.

Comment: Is there any structure/pattern to components or are these values random?

Comment: The problem is NP-hard, as pointed out above, but instances that occur in real life are usually easy.  If you have a real-life problem, then tell us what you can about the expected number and size of the components, the size of the target, the distribution of component sizes, and any common factors.

Comment: @MrSmith42 Unfortunately I need the closest possible combination of components that would reach zero even if zero can't perfectly be reached. (e.g position = 1260, components = [500, 250]). Is backtracking still be applicable?

Comment: @Thomas The components are random, but there will typically be no more than three and they will often have a common factor.

Comment: @Archie Vawser; backtracking (and also DFS) are still possible if you cannot reach 0 exactly. But in this case you will explore the hole search space because you never know if you can get nearer to 0 without trying all possibilities (in some cases you might be able to skip some cases because they cannot get better than the best so far known solution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function getCombinations(array, rest) {
  function test(state, col) {
    let best = state;
    const value = array[col];

    // what's the most I can subtract with this value?
    const max = Math.floor(state.rest / value);
    // if this is the last column to check (0), subtracting 4*value, 3*, 2*, ...
    // will not yield a better result that subtracting 5*value
    // so check only the max value.
    const min = col ? 0 : max;

    for (let i = max; i >= min; --i) {
      const tmp = i ? {
        ...state,
        [value]: i,
        rest: state.rest - value * i
      } : state;
      
      const item = col ? test(tmp, col - 1) : tmp;

      // no need to check any further
      if (item.rest === 0) return item;

      if (item.rest < best.rest) best = item;
    }

    // log checked state; since this function is recursive, 
    // avoid logging the same `best` for each `col`
    col || console.log("checked", best);

    return best;
  }

  // copy and sort ASC
  array = [...array].sort((a, b) => a - b);

  const state = { rest };
  array.forEach(value => state[value] = 0); // optional

  // going from right to left (hi to lo) so that I don't have to 
  // check `col < array.length-1` all the time. 
  // this way I can check for `col !== 0` or simply `col?`
  return test(state, array.length - 1);
}

// get 3 random values
const set = new Set();
while (set.size < 3) set.add(Math.floor(Math.random() * 999 + 1));

console.log("values", ...set);

console.log(getCombinations(set, 2250));
```

technically this is a brute-force algorithm trying combinations but with some short circuiting. Like avoiding some pointless combinations and returning early when a combination is found with remainder: 0.

And it works backwards from highest to lowest value, trying to reduce the remainder as much as possible and then checking if there is a better result with a lower count for this value to ensure that when there are multiple possible results it finds the one with the lowest count first.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a backtracking and use an ordered array for having the largest values first.

```js
function getSum(array, sum) {
    function iter(index, temp, left) {
        if (!left) return temp;
        if (left < 0 || index >= array.length) return;
        return iter(index, [...temp, array[index]], left - array[index])
            || iter(index + 1, temp, left);
    }

    return iter(0, [], sum);
}

console.log(getSum([1000, 750, 500], 2250));
```

Comment: This would be perfect, but it returns undefined when it can't perfectly reach zero (e.g 2251). Is it possible to tweak this that so that it instead returns the combination that was the closest possible to reaching zero?